# Как передавать данные клиенту через сервер моментально?

Tags: сервер, клиент-сервер

Каким образом можно передавать данные серверу вот прям моментально(не в локальной сети), без сокетов?

Comment: Увы, теория относительности и конечная скорость света препятствуют осуществлению вашего желания

Comment: На чем сервер? На чем клиент? Почему нельзя сокеты? Если вас не устраивает первоначальное время инициализации соединения HTTP(S), то используйте HTTP keep-alive чтобы лишний раз не инициализировать подключение, а использовать уже открытое.

Comment: Клиент и сервер на python. Но в итоге было принято решение написать на django сервис для управление скриптом удалённо.